# How can I know which Image on the ImageButton is?

Tags: android, image, imagebutton

I'm using a ImageButton which should change his image after every click. This is my code which doesn't run:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageButton button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
}

View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(button.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.lok))
        {
            button.setBackgroundResource(0);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lok2);
        }

    }
};}
```

I know that this part should be wrong: if(button.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.lok))

Someone has a other solution for it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to change image on every click ? How many images ?

Comment: There are max. 8 images. Could be less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Tag`. Set Tag for a button using `setTag()` and when click of button `getTag()`. [Here is an example for that](http://jongladwin.blogspot.in/2010/03/androidsettag-and-gettag-usage-for.html).

Comment: Thanks alot. I was exactly looking for that. Answer accepted in 3 mins ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the `Tag` of Imagebutton.
 for example, setTag(X) whenever you set ImageButton's Background.
 then you can compare its Tag & then change its background & tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this **

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        if(button.getBackground().equals(R.drawable.lok))
        {

            if(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag())== R.drawable.lok2){

            }else{

            }
            button.setBackgroundResource(0);
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lok2);
            button.setTag(R.drawable.lok2);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have 5 images to change then use an `int i` variable

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  ImageButton button;
  int i=0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
     button.setOnClickListener(imgButtonHandler);
  }

    View.OnClickListener imgButtonHandler = new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {

        button.setBackgroundResource(0);
        switch (i % 5) {
    case 0:
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image0);
        break;
    case 1:
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);
        break;
    case 2:
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image2);
        break;
    case 3:
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image3);
        break;
    case 4:
        button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image4);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
     i++;
   }
  };
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the image of button when you click the button.
First, you should in res/value add some information about the image.
then
If we need to exchange 3 pictrues,only need to creat selector.xme int res/drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/t3"/>
        <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/t1"/>
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/t2"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/t3"/>
</selector>
```

so sorry my English is not good and my way is only i tried ago

Answer (score 0):

try like that

```
 Drawable fDraw = button.getBackground();
 Drawable sDraw = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.lok);

  if(fDraw.hashCode() == sDraw.hashCode())
  {
   //same
  }
else
{
//not same
}
}
```